# C Macro function argument in multiple lines

Tags: c++, c, macros

When a macro function is defined as shown in the `if` block it throws me the error.
Where as the the macro function defined in the `else` block works fine.

Please tell me if there is a way where I could make the macro in the `if` block work as expected.

```
#if 1

#define FREE            \
        (               \
            ptr         \
        )               \
        {               \
            free(ptr);  \
            ptr = NULL; \
        }

#else

#define FREE(ptr)                   \
        {                           \
            free(ptr);              \
            ptr = NULL;             \
        }

#endif

int main(void)
{

    FREE(p);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: what is your compiler / preprocessor? what is the error?

Comment: You need the *funky* `do{}while()` GIYF

Comment: It's treated as an object macro because of the space (explained in the linked question).  It would also be wise to do `do{...}while(0)` instead o `{...}` so you could do `if (x) FREE(p); else someting_else();`.

Comment: IMHO, you should create an actual function, place into a header with `static` specifier and additionally suggest to the compiler to `inline` the function.  If you get compilation issues, you may not be programming in C++, but C.